How to execute command if previous command fails with return code 0
I have a script which logs in to a server. Regardless of the success (i.e. whether the password is valid or not) the script will exit with return code 0, and the text:
Error login failed.

I'd like it to retry login if this happens by running another command, but because of the return code I can't.
If I pipe the output to grep for 'Error' so I can execute a command based on that then the login dialog doesn't show up in the terminal.
Is there anyway around this?
Pseudo code as this is for work:
loginCmd && echo "$?"
username:
password:

Error login failed. 
0

Update
I tried using an idea from a commentator, but I can't capture the text with 'Error' as that line occurs after the command completes...
Here's what it actually looks like, with incorrect password:
agent registration
username: xyz
password:

Error login failed.

I tried this:
result=$(loginCmd | tee /dev/tty)

grep -q 'Error' <<< "$result" && 
    loginCmd

The error string outputs after the command completes, so result doesn't capture it:
result=agent registration

So I guess there is no way to capture this string?
Error login failed.

Any ideas?
Ideally on login failure the script would return 1, or have some sort of retry mechanism, but it doesn't and I can't change that, it's a company script and this only affects the terminal, not the GUI which is what customers use.

Return code 0 usually means success, with non-zero codes indicating one of possibly several errors. Does your code really return zero on failure?

it's a login program at work, whether the login passes or fails it returns 0, I didn't create it, it's company software

so you don't really care about the return code after all, right? You want to re-run it when it returns zero after failing, but not when it returns after succeeding?

reading the output without affecting the prompt is a pretty good question, though... The usual script + piping paradigm would circumvent that by not prompting, but instead passing all data as arguments... but you probably don't want that for passwords

well the problem is it always returns 0. if the login fails it returns 0 so I can't run the login command again, the only difference when it fails to login is you get an error message, anything I can do with that or a solution?

I can't change the return code as it is company software

you could build an expect script to "talk" with the login program, and maybe return a different exit status based on the output. Or cheaper and dirtier: loginCmd | tee tempfile and then grep error tempfile, but I suspect that will break somehow

Thank you, that's a good idea, I'll try it

"whether the login passes or fails it returns 0" - that's different to what you implied in your question

"I can't change the return code as it is company software" - actually, if it's company software this would be a good opportunity for you to present a business case to fix the clearly incorrect exit status. ROI = the amount of time you'll have to spend working around the bug vs the amount of time taken to fix the bug properly

it doesn't matter for end users as they use the GUI which will remain open with the error message. This is terminal only.

Your loginCmd was successful ($? -eq 0). It successfully opened a connection, and sent stuff back and forth until the othrr end shut down the connection.  A successful conversation!

you're missing the point

Hey @ilkkachu please see my update

If this is purely TTY, then you can use expect to run the program, check for this string in the output and either provide more input or run a command.

Your theory doesn’t make sense: loginCmd cannot output the error message after loginCmd completes.   Maybe it writes the error message to stderr, or maybe directly to the tty.   What happens if you run loginCmd 2> /dev/null?   How about result=$(loginCmd 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty)?

it appears in tty but I'll try, what seems to be happening is it returns 0 (could be a function) rather than exit 0 then outputs the message, I'll give it a go @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica'

@muru I read about expect and it seems to be it's own thing even has it's own extension, I'll give it a try, how am I going to run expect in a bash script? it has it's own shell, I'll try though

thank you @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' that worked perfectly much appreciated

An expect solution might look like this
#!/usr/bin/env expect -f
set looping true
while {$looping} {
  spawn loginCmd
  interact {
    -o
    "Error Login failed." { puts "Try again"; return }
    "login successful"    { set looping false }
  }
}


Mixing shell and expect is basically a matter of invoking expect just like any other command. The tricky part is ensuring that the quoting is correct, and that expect variables are not inadvertently expanded by the shell
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "do some bash stuff first ..."

# a shell variable you want to use in expect, put it in the environment
export username="john doe"

# the expect code gets sent to expect on its stdin.
# a quoted heredoc quotes the whole document.
# shell variables are accessed through the expect `env` array.
expect << 'END_EXPECT'
    puts "hello $env(username)"

    set looping true
    while {$looping} {
      spawn loginCmd
      interact {
        -o
        "Error Login failed." { puts "Try again"; return }
        "login successful"    { set looping false }
      }
    }
END_EXPECT


That only works if the password is foobar I believe the OP wants a test for user that exist on the "Agent Registration" server regardless of password... Nice expect though.

can't do this as the loginCmd part is the last part of a bash script which has many functions doing other stuff, I only added it as that was the problem, also this isn't a script which  does read it runs the company software, which has many parts, coupling it all. Yes exactly what @eyoung100 said

I'm not suggesting you replace your loginCmd with that little shell script. As I indicated, that was just to test the expect code. replace spawn loginCmd with spawn whatever you do to invoke your login command. It is straightforward to embed expect code in a shell script.

oh right so you can have expect in shell scripts? How does that work? From what I read it is it's own thing, I find it hard to understand as it expect scripts have their own extension, feels to me like mixing bash and zsh, I like the concept of expect

also should this: { puts "Try again"; return } not be: { loginCmd; return 0} else it would just exit with the message if I am understanding it correctly? I'll find a use for  expect, thanks

well actually the loop would continue so you'd get the message and loginCmd would be called again

Yes, that return returns from the interact command.

Alternately, as expect is an extension of the general purpose language Tcl, you could write your whole script in expect. Tcl is quite a simple language it only has 12 rules.

thanks I'll have a look

I'm going to give you the answer after learning about expect and you changing it to be in bash, for my case I'd remove all the output, but this is a very useful thing I've learned, thanks, and it does things much nicer instead of pairing many commands.

is the env shebang required for expect when doing this? you're only using bash for it, so no? Just cos some distros have the path somewhere else (I don't want to have to worry about that) like in mac it might be in /opt/homebrew; mac comes with bash 3 and you have to install bash 5 which is in the homebrew dir then set chsh to that dir which contains bash 5 @glennjackman

For example running as bash without the shebang will use the shell  you have set your env to be. This script does mac, centos, ubuntu and debian

what I'm really asking is if I set the shebang like you have then my script won't be agnostic of all the OSs I'm using causing me headache so is it necessary to add it? @glennjackman

Are you asking about #!/usr/bin/env bash versus #!/bin/bash? The one with env will use the bash from your PATH. Handy when you're installing homebrew bash and then you don't need to update the shebang for your scripts. If you launch your scripts with bash script.sh then the shebang is just a regular comment.

alright thanks for the clarification on why you had the env shebang, now I see a good use for that shebang, on my bash5 installed by homebrew it's located in another dir rather than the standard one, that's useful info, I could move it there or symlink it, but this is a nicer solution

This is a weird case and many thanks to everyone that helped sincerely. Many would've written it off just because of how strange or hard to communicate it was.
Props to Ikkachu (always a good contributer to my stuff) and G man.
Here's what I done:
while true; do
    result=$(loginCmd 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty)

    if grep -q 'Error' <<< "$result"; then
        loginCmd
    else
        break
    fi
done

Output:
agent registration
username: xyz
password: 
Error Login failed.
agent registration
username:xyz
password: 
login successful

It also didn't break getting the login right the first time.
I added the loop so it keeps prompting no matter how many times the password is entered wrong.
If anyone has any suggestions to make this better I'm open to it, I learned a lot here.
